# Is my array empty or not?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2

I have an array that becomes loaded with objects when I call it in my `viewDidLoad` method. I know that it is not empty because I am able to print the data and the count of the array when I call it in `viewDidLoad`.

However, when I try to take the data out of the array and put it into a text view, the array appears to be empty. The code below is where I attempt to add the items from requestList2 into a textfield in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Why does does my array possess data when I call it in `viewDidLoad`, but not when I try to add it to `cell.usernameOfRequestSender.text`?

```
if (requestList2.count > 0){
  var user = requestList2.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String
  cell.usernameOfRequestSender.text = user
}

return cell
```

Comment: Use the debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: Xcode is not showing a error in the code. The code runs, it just does not go through the if statement when I try to add it to a text view in a cell of my TableView. I am assuming this is because the array is empty at this point. However, when I call another function containing the array in ViewDidLoad, I am able to print the contents and count of the array. Why is my array empty in cellForRowAtIndexPath function? Are the cellForRowAtIndexPath functions in a TableViewController called before the ViewDidLoad function?

Comment: Checking for empty of the data source array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is always redundant because it's already done in `numberOfRowsInSection`. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will never be called if the array is empty.

Comment: I guess my question really comes down to why is there objects in my array when I call it in ViewDidLoad then?

Comment: Can you show the code that loads the array?  My guess is you are loading the data asynchronously and not calling `reloadData` on the tableview when you are done

Comment: Yes, Paul you are right. I figured this out last night. Thank you. I can not figure out how to mark your answer as correct though lol.